# How to update from deprecated Supervisor.spec to new Supervisor.behaviour?

Tags: elixir, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

### Background

I am trying to build a supervision tree in my app, where a given GenServer will have to supervise other GenServers. This is not an application, just a simple GenServer that needs to supervise others.

To achieve this I mainly focused my attention on the following article:
http://codeloveandboards.com/blog/2016/03/20/supervising-multiple-genserver-processes/

### Code

The above article led me to the following code:

```
defmodule A.Server do
  use Supervisor

  alias B

  def start_link, do:
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)

  def init(nil) do
    children = [B]
    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

So as you can see, my GenServer `A` is trying to supervise another called `B`.

### Problem

The problem here is that everything in this example is deprecated. I tried following the instructions and read the new [`Supervisor docs`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html), specially `start_child` which I think will be the correct substitute for the deprecated `supervise`, but unfortunately I don't understand how I can apply this to my code.

### Question

How can I update my code so it does not use deprecated functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dedicated section in [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-module-based-supervisors) docs providing the example.

```rb
defmodule A.Server do
  use Supervisor

  alias B

  def start_link, do:
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)

  @impl Supervisor
  def init(_) do
    children = [
      {B, [:arg1, :arg2]} # or just `B` if `start_link/0`
    ]

    Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

Comment: Totally missed on that. It was just a case of not knowing where to looks and looking at the wrong place. Thanks !